# Rank calculation only for valid date using RANK/DENSE_RANK using case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I am trying to calculate the rank based on the date range; if the date is between the ranges, then I want to create the rank; otherwise, I want to keep it either blank/zero. I can achieve this if I have to write multiple lines of query, but I have to do this in a single-case statement.

[image]

The Rank_coming column is highlighted in column using the below code, but I want the values highlighted in Rank_Needed.

```
SELECT *
    , RANK () over (partition by id, order by case when date between '2023-01-01' AND '2023-06-01 00:00:00' then date end) Rank_coming
FROM Table1
```

How can I achieve this using the case statement SQL query?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I can't even see that image on a PC let alone a phone.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: Why does this "have" to be done with a single case expression?

Comment: [NULL values are treated as the lowest possible value.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) So, you should get `2,1,1,1` not `1,2,2,2` (allowing you to use `rank() over (blah) - 1` to get `1,0,0,0`)

Comment: @DaleK Thanks, Will keep this in mind for future reference!

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks; this makes sense. I will try to implement the suggested logic. However, one catch: what about the scenario where you have only one row with a valid date range? In this scenario, it will be 1-1 = 0, even if I have a valid rank. Also, I am trying to use this expression in a big subquery, so I do not want to use seperate query.

Comment: Why wait till next time? Make this a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Id, dates,
       CASE
           WHEN dates BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-06-01' THEN RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dates)
           ELSE 0
       END AS rank_needed
FROM temp;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/uPEkTU9d